# Designing an async data provider with BeginExecuteReader in C#

Tags: c#, async-await

I am new to the async/await model in C# 5 so you will have to be patient with my ignorance/lack of understanding.

I would like to upgrade my Singleton designed data provider to perform an asynchronous call to a stored procedure then return the data using BeginDataReader and EndDataReader methods in the System.Data namespace.

Here is an example of the structure that I am trying to build but it is not waiting for the data to return:

```
public class DataProvider{
    private static DataProvider instance;
    public static DataProvider Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    lock (typeof(DataProvider))
                    {
                        instance = new DataProvider();
                    }
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }

    public virtual async void ExecuteDataReaderAsync(string StoredProcedureName, AsyncCallback callback, params object[] Parameters)
        {
            InitDatabase();
            var connection = new SqlConnection(databaseControllers[connectionStringName].ConnectionString);
            var cmd = new SqlCommand();

            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = dbPrefixName + StoredProcedureName;
            await connection.OpenAsync();

            SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);
            if (cmd.Parameters.Count - 1 > Parameters.Count())
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The number of parameters provided does not match the number of parameters in the stored procedure. There are " + Parameters.Count().ToString() + " parameters provided, however the stored procedure requires " + cmd.Parameters.Count.ToString() + " parameters.");

            for (int i = 0; i < Parameters.Count(); i++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters[i + 1].Value = Parameters[i];
            }

            cmd.BeginExecuteReader(new AsyncCallback(callback), cmd);
        }
}

public class SubDataProvider : DataProvider
{
    private static volatile SubDataProvider instance = new SubDataProvider();
        public static SubDataProvider Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    lock (typeof(SubDataProvider))
                    {
                        if (instance == null)
                            instance = new SubDataProvider();
                    }
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }

    ////
    //// THIS IS WHERE I GET LOST
    ////

        public async Task<List<Models.MyData>> GetDataAsync(bool IncludeDeleted = false)
        {
            List<Models.MyData> temp = new List<MyData>();
            ExecuteDataReaderAsync("GetData", delegate (IAsyncResult result)
            {

                var database = (SqlCommand)result.AsyncState;

                using (IDataReader reader = database.EndExecuteReader(result))
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        temp.Add(FillData(reader));
                    }

                }

                if (database.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    database.Connection.Close();

            }, false);
            return temp;
        }
}


public class BusinessController
{
        private static volatile  BusinessController _instance = new BusinessController();

        public static BusinessController Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    lock (typeof (BusinessController))
                    {
                        _instance = new BusinessController();
                    }
                }
                return _instance;
            }
        }

        public async Task<List<Models.MyData>> GetAllAsync(bool IncludeDeleted = false)
        {
            return await SubDataProvider.Instance.GetDataAsync(IncludeDeleted);;
        }
}


// DEMO
internal class Program
{
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var x = BusinessController.Instance.GetAllAsync(false);
        }
}
```

My ultimate goal is to get this data back to an asynchronous WebApi but I currently am stuck at not getting any data back. The temp variable gets filled but it never actually returns the filled object.

Where am I going wrong?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: You should never do `async void` unless you are writing a event handler. If a exception gets thrown on any line after `await connection.OpenAsync();` you have no way to catch it.

Comment: First of all, Avoid async void unless its an event handler. Because you wont be able to catch any exceptions after await connection.OpenAsync(); 

Second of all, you're populating your `temp` gets populated in the callback, your method returns earlier than that anyway.

Comment: Also you are mixing you are mixing [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx) with [Asynchronous Programming Model (APM)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx). You normally only pick one of the 3 methods of async TAP, EAP, or APM and use just that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have your exact codebase here but something like this would be close to what you need:

Inside class `DataProvider` I renamed `ExecuteDataReaderAsync` to `GetDataReaderAsync`

```
public virtual async Task<IDataReader> GetReaderAsync(string StoredProcedureName, params object[] Parameters)
{
    InitDatabase();
    var connection = new SqlConnection(databaseControllers[connectionStringName].ConnectionString);
    var cmd = new SqlCommand
    {
        Connection = connection,
        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
        CommandText = dbPrefixName + StoredProcedureName
    };

    await connection.OpenAsync();

    SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);
    if (cmd.Parameters.Count - 1 > Parameters.Count())
        throw new InvalidOperationException("The number of parameters provided does not match the number of parameters in the stored procedure. There are " + Parameters.Count().ToString() + " parameters provided, however the stored procedure requires " + cmd.Parameters.Count.ToString() + " parameters.");

    for (int i = 0; i < Parameters.Count(); i++)
    {
        cmd.Parameters[i + 1].Value = Parameters[i];
    }

    var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    return reader;
}
```

And used the reader in `GetDataAsync` inside class `SubDataProvider`

```
public async Task<List<MyData>> GetDataAsync(bool IncludeDeleted = false)
{
    List<MyData> temp = new List<MyData>();
    using (var reader = await GetReaderAsync("GetData"))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            temp.Add(FillData(reader));
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

I can't test the solution with what I have here but if you opt for sending back a `SqlDataReader` instead of a `IDataReader`, you'd have a `ReadAsync()` method at your disposal too. But since you already have an async method for that now, it would be just fine to use `reader.Read()`. I ditched the callback as it's better to stay with the Task-Asynchronous Paradigm here.

Hope this helps. :)

#### Update

From @Scott Chamberlain in the comments, one other suggestion would be to keep the reader in `DbDataReader` level instead of `IDataReader` so you can still be generic and have access to methods like `ReadAsync()`. The suggestion deemed worthy, thus added in the answer here.

Comment: One change I would suggest, change `cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();` to `cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)`. This will cause the connection object to be closed once the reader is disposed, very useful for situations like this where you are returning a reader but are not returning or are being passed in the connection the reader is using.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain excellent suggestion to be honest. Changed accordingly.

Comment: Also, by returning a `IDataReader` instead of a `SqlDataReader` you do loose a lot of the nice functionality that is specific to `SqlDataReader` like `ReadAsync()`, if you still want to be generic return a `DbDataReader`, that gives you more methods than `IDataReader` but is still generic.

Comment: That worked beautifully! Thank you so much! I do appreciate how simple and elegant that was!

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it. Happy to help. Marking my answer as the "answer" would make me happier. :P 

@ScottChamberlain, indeed, thought of that. I was not sure whether the Questioner wanted it to keep it on IDataReader level or not. 

I'm mentioning that in the answer. Thanks.